# Maven deployed JARS from artifactory are not downloaded when they are given as dependency

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have created a jar file using maven and deployed it to local artifactory. I can see the jar file and pom in artifactory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany.hr</groupId>
<artifactId>hotel-schema</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.hr</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>

<name>jaxb-schema Spring-WS Application</name>
<url>http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws</url>
<build>
    <finalName>hotel-schema</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- The package of your generated sources -->
                <sources>
                    <source>../holidayService/src/main/xsd</source>
                </sources>
                <packageName>com.example.myschema</packageName>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/jaxb</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Babu-Dell-releases</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local-maven-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Babu-Dell-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local-maven-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

However when I try to add the jar as dependency to another project, it is not getting downloaded. There is no error I can see.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.hr</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>holidayService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>holidayService Spring-WS Application</name>
<url>http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws</url>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-internal-site</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local-maven-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <finalName>holidayService</finalName>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.hr</groupId>
        <artifactId>hotel-schema</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Babu-Dell-releases</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local-maven-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Babu-Dell-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local-maven-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Please help

Please find attached the image in my local repository[image of local repository][1]

Also please find below the settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<servers>
<server>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>{YBoEnaZCnnEHquaMcfJGpTjh0I7i+vQAv9a2+CQL9ZE=}</password>
  <id>central</id>
</server>
<server>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>{YBoEnaZCnnEHquaMcfJGpTjh0I7i+vQAv9a2+CQL9ZE=}</password>
  <id>snapshots</id>
</server>
</servers>
<profiles>
<profile>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local-maven-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local-maven-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>plugins-release</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <id>artifactory</id>
</profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
<activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

[Image of eclipse maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BO2Z.png)

[Artifactory server jar file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWRqI.png)

Comment: Can you also share the ERROR ? Is it unauthorized? NOT FOUND?

Comment: I guess it's already in your local repo `~/.m2/repository`. Especially if it is the same machine from where you deployed it. @Gangaraju: "_There is no error I can see._".

Comment: Yes there is no error. I can see the file in my local repo also.

Comment: I have also added an image of the local repository where the jar is getting created and I have also pasted the settings.xml which I have in .m2 folder

Comment: You write "_it is not getting downloaded._" Why do you think it should? It's in your local repo already, so why should it be downloaded again? If you really want to download it again (for instance, because you deployed the same release version a second time, which is discouraged for obvious reasons) delete the appropriate folder in your local repo.

Comment: But maybe there's a misunderstanding. You write "_local artifactory_". There is just one _local_ repo for Maven and it's the mentioned `~/.m2/repository`. Everything else is a _remote_ repo: may it be internal, company-wise, or even on the same machine. See [Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).

Comment: Thanks Gerold and Michele for your replies.

Comment: Actually I tried both. I first didn't have artifactory installed. I did maven install on the first pom. I could see that the jar is getting generated in my local repository. However when I did a build on the second POM, the jar was not downloaded from local.  Based on some posts, I felt I needed an artifactory for it to work and hence I downloaded artifactory and configured it. Then I did mvn deploy. The jar is available in artifactory also in the exact same way.  However I cannot see the jar in eclipse as dependecy and hence I am not able to use it.

Comment: Now I didnt do this before. I thought of unpacking the war created using mvn install on the second pom. What I could find is the hotel-schema.jar downloaded and in the lib folder.  Now I wonder why doesn't eclipse show the jar in the maven dependencies and let me use the classes in the jar

Comment: I have updated the images to show the artifactory and the eclipse screenshots. Looks like an eclipse issue more than maven

Comment: The screenshot [Artifactory server jar file image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pWRqI.png) shows `local-maven-snaphots` but `hotel-schema-1.0` isn't a snapshot version. It's a _release_ version. See [Understanding Maven Version Numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN401)

Comment: Yes the name is confusing.In  local-maven-snapshots repository both handle releases and handle snapshots are checked

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a bit of confusion here. You probably installed artifactory locally and you properly configured your maven settings.xml to point to it, but in your screenshot you are showing us the maven local repository under your .m2 folder.

They are 2 different repository as already stated by Gerold.

If you want your artifact to go on your LOCAL repo (i.e. your .m2/repository folder) you must invoke mvn install goal, while to deploy your artifact to REMOTE artifactory you have to invoke maven deploy goal and have a [distributionManagement](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) configured in your project which tell the project where to deploy.

If you just want to work locally you have no need to install artifactory, simply use your local repository (maven will do this for you out-of-the-box, so you can remove all the additional repository section in your settings.xml and the distributionManagement section.

Artifactory is extremely useful for team work, but should not be hosted locally but on a shared server where all team members can access. 
In any case, if you want to use it, you should check from its web interface if the artifact has been properly deployed.

Finally, as already asked, which is the error you got after a "mvn clean deploy" command ? there may be many reason why artifact has been installed locally (as per your screenshot) but not remotely (on artifactory)

Answer (score 0):

Appears that your profile not enabled, make it active by default or else give id to profile and append -PprofileId in your command, it should download.

Comment: This should probably be left as a comment, not a standalone answer